# SSIS and Foreign Keys

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

I created an SSIS package that takes in a CSV file and imports it into a table called "OPEX_Spend".

I added a foreign key to the OPEX_Spend table but when I run the query, the  Account_ID column in the OPEX_Spend table shows up as "NULL". Why is that? Do I have to incorporate some sort of lookup in the data flow? Currently the data flow is the following:

- Flat File Source
- OLE DB Destination

Here is how the tables are set up:

```
CREATE TABLE OPEX_Accounts 
(
    OPEX_ID int IDENTITY (1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    OPEX_Name varchar(50),
    GL_Account varchar(50)
)

CREATE TABLE OPEX_Spend 
(
    Actuals_ID int IDENTITY (1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    Account_ID int,

    CONSTRAINT FK_OPEXID 
        FOREIGN KEY (OPEX_ID) REFERENCES OPEX_Accounts (OPEX_ID),
    Actuals_Date varchar(50),
    Transaction_Text varchar (50),
    Actuals_Amount numeric
)
```

Comment: What is the query?

Comment: SELECT * FROM OPEX_Spend

Comment: Likely what you are looking for is a lookup transform component. You can put it in your data flow task and use it to find the OPEX_ID using some other identifier from your source data. Depending on what your data is like, it might take either OPEX_Name, GL_Account, or a combination of the two to find the ID.

Comment: I see. The source data has all the OPEX names that are listed in the OPEX_Accounts table. What tables do I create the lookup for? Between OPEX_Spend and the source data?

Comment: See the answer.

Comment: Thanks. Let me try this and I'll report back.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139904/discussion-between-mallan1121-and-max).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a Lookup Transformation on your data flow task to do this:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/data-flow/transformations/lookup-transformation

Basically you will need to use the account name in your source data as the join with the account name in OPEX_Accounts to get the OPEX_ID. Then you can configure your lookup transformation to add the OPEX_ID as a new column in your pipeline, and map that to your destination table.

Also it is important to decide how to treat source rows that do not yield a valid lookup. You can have these throw errors that stop your package from running, or direct them to a special no match output.

Comment: Hey! So I got the foreign key column to populate but when I run a query, it repeats my table numerous times. For example, there should be 336 rows but the query shows 1002, so there are about 3 iterations of the table. Any ideas why?